# How does frequency recording works with speakers exactly?

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency, speaker

I'm currently trying to make my Android application based on frequencies work but I encounter some issues with speakers. 
In fact, I obtained three different results, depending of the method I use. Here are the methods, and the result for a 440 Hz sound (A for audiophiles) :

- **Method 1** : I use my voice directly in the application.

**Result** : 
[Method 1 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HduWo.png)

Average Frequency : 443 Hz. Good result.

- **Method 2** : I record my voice through the default Android recording application, add this file in my application Firebase database and play it with my application.

**Result** : 
[Method 2 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhoLx.png)

Average Frequency : 224 Hz. Frequencies are divided by 2 ?!

- **Method 3** : I play a 440 Hz sound found on Youtube with my laptop and record it directly with my application.

**Result** : 
[Method 3 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8nZs.png)

Average Frequency : 886 Hz. Frequencies are multiplied by 2 now ?!

- **Method 4** : Same method as the second one but I don't use the default Android recording application. I use EasyVoiceRecorder where I can configure the sample rate (I put 44 kHz) and the encoding (I put .wav).

**Result** : 
[Method 4 Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4we0I.png)

Average Frequency : 431 Hz. Good result.

**Additional informations** :

- To save the files in Firebase database as WAV files, I use [AndroidAudioConverter library](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter) in order to not manipulate different audio formats and take advantage of WAV headers informations.
- I use AudioTrack and AudioRecord classes and then Fast Fourier
  Transform to get the main frequencies every 128 ms. AudioRecord is
  configured with 44.1 kHz sample rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO and
  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT. AudioTrack is configured according to
  WAV header file information.
- When I play sounds located in raw application folder, frequencies
  result is perfect.

I don't really see the point in sharing the code of my application because as I showed you, it doesn't work only if I use third-party devices (default recording application, laptop, ...), so it must be a hardware issue. But if you need some code pieces, ask me and I will give them to you.

Thanks for reading, thanks in advance for your help and... happy coding ! :D

Comment: The sound you record will almost never be a pure sine wave but a mixture of several sine waves with different frequencies. It seems your program has some difficulties to identify the strongest sine in the signal.

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure ? I'm documented on frequencies, so I know sound is combination of several sine waves. However, in order to get the main frequency of the signal, I use FFT (amplitude/frequency) and get the frequency with the highest amplitude. It works everytime for raw folder audio files and with my voice recorded directly in the application.
Why wouldn't it work only when I use a phone playing the same sound as my voice ? I don't get how it could be a code issue here...

Comment: You are mistaken to think this is a hardware issue; if it is not one of deciding which component is strongest, then almost certainly, what you are seeing is mono/stereo or sample width misinterpretations.  But without *actual details* others can compare, this reduces to a prohibited "usage" question.  Hint: try *playing back the sound from your own code* to see if you have mixed up its interpretation, your ears will tell you right away, especially if you record voice.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was trying to debugging according what you said.
I think I get it. For the method 2, it's certainly because of the conversion because wav header from m4a converted file indicates that the file is stereo, instead of easyvoicerecorder which tells that the file is mono and gives the correct frequencies. Furthermore, I don't hear any differencies between the two files in term of tone.
For method 3, I think laptop emits a stereo sound but my AudioRecord is configured in mono, because when I configure it in stereo, I get the correct frequencies.

Comment: However, how can I fix these problems ? 
How can I replace the AndroidAudioConverter system ? And for method 3, how can I know if sound is emitted by a computer or simply by voice ?

Comment: We generally expect to see some code in questions like this  - it's hard to provide an answer otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If you use an FFT for spectral frequency magnitude peak picking, then any harmonics or intermodulation products that are stronger than the fundamental pitch frequency will confuse the result.

Youtube and many recording applications compress audio.  One of the affects of lower quality compression is the distortion of frequency spectrum.  Also, playing audio out of a laptop's small speakers, which have poor low frequency response, will also distort the frequency spectrum.

Solutions include not using compressed audio formats, using much larger speakers with a lower flatter frequency response, and using a better [pitch detection/estimation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm) instead of just picking an FFT magnitude peak.